# When importing a .txt, Excel converts number to date

Tags: microsoft-excel

something really weird is happenning: I have opened a .txt file that only contains a bunch of decimal numbers, delimited through a Carriage Return.

Now, Excel has converted a few of these numbers into a date. For example the number 24.10 gets converted to 24. Okt

I am using the German language, but I have converted the decimal character from a comma to a point.

Anyways, when I mark the cells and try to format everything to be a number, these dates (e.g. 24. Okt) become strange numbers. 24. Okt for example becomes 43762.0

I don't know why this is happening, can anyone help? 
I actually have to perform calculations with these values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you import the .txt using the Excel Text Import Wizard, you can specify the type of each column of data. That way, you can control exactly how Excel interprets your data.

([This Office Support article](https://support.office.com/en-ie/article/text-import-wizard-c5b02af6-fda1-4440-899f-f78bafe41857) explains it in more detail because I don't currently have a Windows computer at hand to screenshot.)

Comment: perfect, thx a lot!